# How to remove "Decimal" keyword from the output

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
S_acc=[Decimal('14674.04881484484319092894299'),Decimal('1287243.594400802980099508539')]
```

I would like to have output in this form:

```
S_acc=[14674.04881484484319092894299, 1287243.594400802980099508539]
```

I tried converting into string first before converting to decimal number but I am getting this error:

```
results = [tuple(str(item) for item in t) for t in s_acc]
print(results)

TypeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object is not iterable
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You cannot have them as floats, you lose accuracy that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, it's just:

```
>>> [str(d) for d in S_acc]
['14674.04881484484319092894299', '1287243.594400802980099508539']
```

Use [format specs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) if you want more control over the representation.